# I am using spring web-5.2.24 but i want to upgrade it to higher version as it has vulnerabilties

Tags: spring, boot

I am using spring web-5.2.24 but i want to upgrade it to higher version as it has vulnerabilties. but I am getting an error saying java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError. how can I update to version without updatimg jdk. please help

solution to my question

Comment: Spring 6 requires JDK17. Also you shouldnt' be upgrading single modules from a framework but rather the whole framework else you will run into weird issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.